# Can you stop a page from reloading on form submit without preventDefault with svelte kit?

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

I want to display a toast for a few seconds whenever a user does something, eg. when they log in to the app. I am using a form on `/login/+page.svelte` to login, with the database interaction in `/login/page.server.js`.  And I am using a `writable store` to store toasts.

On form submit, the page refreshes, so my store is cleared and the toast is lost. It seems the event flow is:

- submit form to `/login/page.server.js`
- `page.server.js` does some stuff
- `page.server.js` sends back the full page and the browser reloads to the new full page.

I understand you can use `preventdefault` to prevent all those steps, but I only want to prevent the reloading. Preventing everything does not seem optimal (there are probably some other stuff I don't even know I'm preventing).

Is there a nicer way of interacting between a `page.svelte` and a `page.server.js` without reload (and thus clearing, probably all, stores) than preventdefault + using a manual fetch?

REPL I was playing around with that demonstrates the toast staying full 3 seconds generally, but immediately disappearing on normal form submit.
https://svelte.dev/repl/8b61434332ca471b83cbf039bf1f3fc9?version=3.22.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The intended workflow for forms is to use [form actions](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/form-actions) and [`enhance`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/form-actions#progressive-enhancement-use-enhance), which automatically processes the form asynchronously (which falls back to the hard reload if JS is disabled).

Comment: Are there any examples?

Comment: @ramory-l: See the linked docs.